# How to implement Azure AD single tenant auth in React and standalone Golang Web API?

Tags: reactjs, azure, oauth-2.0, active-directory

We have a React application created with Create-React-App. Right now, it's being served with nginx:alpine in a docker container in Azure App Services. I don't care much about the server since it only serves the built react app as static files.

Aside from that, we also have a golang api running standalone in another container in Azure App Services. Now what we want to do is when a user points to the React app URL, he/she will be redirected to login.microsoft.com/xxxxx..... or the popup will show. User will signin, then that will be the time he can access the application.

I've read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-developers-guide) but being fairly new to these concepts, and to web development in general, I'm confused a bit on how to start this. I understand the flow but I can't implement it yet.

I've tried the Browser to Web App scenario in NodeJS but I guess it is for server side rendering. So my option is to use ADAL which does not have React implementation in their docs. And their ADAL JS samples have the spa being served at the same app with the API.

Now, for my specific situation, React's server is different than the API. So I don't really know how to continue. Can someone at least point me to a working example of my situation? Or enumerate what I have to do? I don't need code, just a method that will take me there.

But if this can be done correctly, I think I'll do the method below:

**Web Browser to Web Application** scenario

```
// Use the passport-azure-ad and OIDC strategy in the docs and samples
// Configure express
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    if (!req.user) {
        // res.render the template which has link to login
    } else {
        // res.sendFile the React's index.html
    }
});

app.get('/login',
  passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', { failureRedirect: '/login' 
  }),
  function(req, res) {
    log.info('Login was called in the Sample');
    res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Although I doubt it because I tried the method above and it only served the html and chrome says "http://localhost:3000/static/css/xxxxxxxx.css" and the JS file both don't exist even though I pointed it correctly in the public folder.

Also, with the above method, I can't use the `app.get("*", xxxx)` which I need to prevent "File Not Found" when browser is refreshed.

So if I can't do it like the above method, what's the solution?

Comment: I'm in the exact same boat. It's so much work to get auth included in here.

Comment: I'm also trying to figure out this, stumbling since last few days. Did you figure out anything for this problem?